# Inverse Function Theorem proof: f is injective

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, frechet-derivative, inverse-function-theorem

I am trying to prove the Inverse Function Theorem from the Implicit Function Theorem for Banach spaces. My attempt so far is as follows:

Let $f:\mathbf{X}\to \mathbf{Y}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function between Banach spaces, and let $x^*\in\mathbf{X}$ and $y^*:=f(x^*)$ be such that the Fréchet derivative $\mathrm{d}\,f(x^*):\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{Y}$ is bounded with bounded inverse.

Consider $F:\mathbf{X}\times\mathbf{Y}\to\mathbf{Y}$ given by $F(x,y):=f(x)-y$. Then the partial Fréchet derivative $\partial_xF(x^*,y^*)\equiv \mathrm{d}\,f(x^*)$ is bounded with a bounded inverse, so $F$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Implicit Function Theorem. Hence, there are open sets $U\subseteq\mathbf{X}$ and $V\subseteq\mathbf{Y}$ containing $x^*$ and $y^*$, respectively, and a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function $g:V \to U$ such that $F(g(y), y) = 0$ for all $y\in V$, i.e. $f(g(y)) = y$.

The above shows that $g$ is a *right* inverse of $f$, but I want to be able to conclude, further, **that $g$ is a *left* inverse of $f$ on $U$, i.e. $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in U$**. I know this to be equivalent to showing that the restriction $f|_U$ is injective (possibly by choosing a smaller neighbourhood of $x^*$ in $U$), but I am not sure how to do this.

I would greatly appreciate any hints!

Comment: Doesn't the classical formulation of the implicit function theorem say $f:X\oplus Y \to Z$ etc

Comment: @JJR Are you referring to my writing '$X \times Y$' instead of '$X \oplus Y$? The statement of the theorem as I know it has $F$ defined on an open set $W \subseteq X \times Y$ (I have taken $W = X \times Y$ for simplicity).

Comment: Oh sry my mistake I thought you were proving implicit function theorem from inverse function theorem not the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ satisfies the same assumptions as $f$ as a function $V\to U$, we can rerun the proof on $g$ this time to find smaller neighborhoods $U'\subset U$ of $x^*$ and $V'\subset V$ of $y^*$, as well as a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function $h: U' \to V'$ such that

$$ g(h(x)) = x  \quad\text{for all}\quad x \in U'.$$

Now, on $V'$, $g$ has both a left ($f|_{U'}$) and a right ($h$) inverse, so $g|_{V'} : V' \to U'$ is invertible and we have

$$ g^{-1} = h = f. $$